# share hangout app link

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-api, google-hangouts

I recently wrote a hangout app. The workflow is like this:

1. The first user initiates the app by passing the gid parameter to the hangout link. This starts a hangout session with the app.
2. Now once the app opens I grab the hangout URL and send it to other participants.

The problem is that the participants are able to join the hangout but are not able to see the app request as the first user saw. Is there a way we can share the URL with information that says, open this app when you start participating....something like that?

I want the same behavior for every new participant as that of the first user i.e asks permissions etc. for installation of new app

Answer (score 1):

If you start your hangout app from a hangout button and you set initial_apps, where you have the hangout app ID, there is another attribute 'app_type' which has 2 possible values 'ROOM_APP' (hangout app should be started by all participants), 'LOCAL_APP' (hanngout app should start just for the first participant, the broadcaster)

Source: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button#initial_app_parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open hangouts with your app set to ROOM_APP without using the official G+ Hangouts API, you can reverse engineer the URL their JS is making. I did this work, and you can read more about it here: http://vincentwoo.com/2015/01/13/creating-google-hangouts-with-apps-via-url/

Long story short, you have to make a blob of the following format. In Ruby:

```ruby
BASE_URL = 'https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_'
ssc_blob = '["",0,null,null,null,[],null,null,null,null,null,0,null,'\
  'null,null,[0],null,null,[],null,"0",null,null,null,null,null,null,'\
  'null,[],[],null,null,null,[],null,null,null,[],null,null,'\
  "[[\"#{APP_ID}\",\"#{INITIAL_DATA}\",2]]]"
BASE_URL + '?ssc=' + Base64.strict_encode64(ssc_blob)
```

This causes hangouts to redirect to a normal session where your app is enshrined as the room app.